# Search field isn't on same line as text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert a search field in my header (black zone) but doesn't work. I want the search field inline with "SimpleCMS"...

See this screenshot to understand:

[image: Search Field]

I want it on the same line as the header text...

There's my HTML code:

```
<div id="header"><h1><?php echo($header_text); ?></h1>
    <div style="float: right;">
        <form action="search.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="q" id="q" value="Search..." />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#header
{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Is this really all the code there is to your page? Does the `?php echo($header_text); ?`-part insert more than just the line saying "SimpleCMS"? Because if so your putting the link stuff saying "Home" and "Blog" and "Profile" into a `<h1>` element and if not where does it come from?

Comment: @Nessuno No, this is only the header zone. It's the code of what you see in the screenshot (except menu)... The `$header_text` is the "SimpleCMS" only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use a `<h1>` element. This will span over the whole width (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)) of the top so that every other element will be placed below it. Use a `<span>` instead and style it according to your needs. Using `position-absolute` as  alpaca lips nao suggests might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Use `position: absolute;`

```
#header
{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}
#header div form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: I don't want it in the menu, I want it in the black zone. Inline with the "SimpleCMS" text...

Comment: Sorry Frederick. I haven't had my coffee yet! Updated.

Comment: It doesn't work. The header crash! [screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/846/captureaof.png/)

Comment: I am going to go hide in the corner now :). Nessuno got it right. Your h1 is spanning the width of the header. Set a width and try floating it, or wrap it as he suggested.